# Find files in Terminal by kind - not extension?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

I have about 50,000 files in a folder tree which show up as the correct "Kind" in Finder ("Sound Designer II audio") but which have no extension.

I want to find all these and rename them to `*.sd2` in Terminal.

Can the `find` command be used to find by "kind" without any extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search all files with a distinctive **kind** use the command:

```
mdfind 'kMDItemKind="Sound Designer II audio"'
```

If this is not sufficient you can also use the type code (yyyy below is a place holder only)

```
mdfind 'kMDItemFSTypeCode="yyyy"'
```

You should be able get an (unknown) type code of a Sound Designer II audio file by executing `mdls "/path/to/Sound Designer II audio file" | grep kMDItemFSTypeCode`

Comment: Fantastic! How would I run a command on each result, like the `-exec` argurment of `find`?

Comment: @Ze'ev Probably some `... | xargs -0 -I mv '{}' ...` thingy